# Why is Safari(Mac OS Monterey) bypassing my VPN and making connections?

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, safari

Im monitoring traffic between a Mac OS device and router. For the purpose of garnering a smaller network capture, I've just restricted activity to web browsing(Capture using Wireshark on the Mac).

The device is running through a VPN application, so all web traffic is directed toward the VPN IP as expected.

However, the device is establishing a single tcp connection through Safari, directly bypassing the VPN config.

I've tried disabling/enabling the VPN connection to see if it was just a 'glitched' tcp stream that stayed alive prior to the VPN's activation.

However, the connection continued as a TCP stream even after turning off/on the VPN config.Traffic suddenly stops for a while after this.

Things that might help to note:

- Connection is to a cloud service(Amazon AWS)
- Presence of a few TLS packets in the stream, but no evidence of a 3-way handshake or Connection close
- A similar TCP has started after this one, whilst VPN is active.

Is this some default capacity of Mac OS' to initiate and/or maintain connections past VPN configurations (Data Analytics, Essential Services)? Would appreciate some insight as I am relatively new to network analysis on Macs

Comment: This is often dependent on the VPN app's split-tunnelling capability.

Comment: For this case the VPN application I'm using NORVPN, I don't have split tunnelling setup or configured. From reading up, seems like NordVPN doesn't have any defaultsplit tunnelling configs . Do you know any use cases where Mac OS itself might be establishing these kind of bypassed connections (i.e Apple Data Analytics).

Comment: I've Edited the title to be a bit more clear. Im trying to make sense of something that's happened, rather then ask if I could do so. Title was misleading

Comment: This isn't something I've ever had to look at, but it sounds like a task [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) might be of help with. It has a free trial.

Comment: To what IP address is this connection?

Comment: Both times were to cloud services, first was AWS(amazon), Second to Nexus(IBM I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Private Relay.
`System Preferences`->`Apple ID`->`iCloud`->`iCloud Private Relay`<kbd>Options...</kbd>-><kbd>Turn Off...</kbd>